Swipe to delete in React native expo weird behaviour
I'm using the react-native-gesture-handler ReanimatedSwipeable and I'm stuck on a weird problem, more I add OrderItems in my list more it is difficult to swipe left to delete the item, for example as I add new items it becomes more difficult to swipe to the left, it almost feels blocking like. When I have let's say three items in my list (three OrderItems), it works perfectly I ca n drag the row left and right as long as I hold my finger on it and then when there's more items it's a chore to even make it move a bit to the left.
Here's my OrderItem component, maybe I didn't implement the react-native-gesture-handler correctly? I really don't know
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {ImageBackground, View} from 'react-native';
import {Product} from '../../types';
import ProductName from '../product/ProductName';
import ProductPrice from '../product/ProductPrice';
import AddQuantityButton from "../add-quantity-button/AddQuantityButton";
import Swipeable, {SwipeableMethods} from 'react-native-gesture-handler/ReanimatedSwipeable';
import {GestureHandlerRootView, RectButton} from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import {Extrapolation, interpolate, SharedValue, useAnimatedStyle} from "react-native-reanimated";
import {Feather} from "@expo/vector-icons";
import {useAppDispatch} from "../../hooks";
import {removeCompletelyFromCart} from "../../store/slices/cartSlice";

type Props = {
    item: Product;
    lastElement?: boolean;
};

interface LeftActionsProps {
    dragX: SharedValue<number>;
    swipeableRef: React.RefObject<SwipeableMethods>;
}

const renderRightActions = (
    _progress: any,
    translation: SharedValue<number>,
    swipeableRef: React.RefObject<SwipeableMethods>
) => <RightAction dragX={translation} swipeableRef={swipeableRef}/>;

const RightAction = ({dragX, swipeableRef}: LeftActionsProps) => {
    const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        transform: [
            {
                translateX: interpolate(
                    dragX.value,
                    [0, 50, 100, 101],
                    [-20, 0, 0, 1],
                    Extrapolation.CLAMP
                ),
            },
        ],
    }));
    return (
        <RectButton
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                alignItems: "flex-end",
                justifyContent: "center",
                width: 50,
                height: 100,
            }}
            onPress={() => swipeableRef.current!.close()}>
            <View style={{padding: 32}}>
                <Feather name="trash" size={20} color="white"/>
            </View>
        </RectButton>
    );
};

const OrderItem: React.FC<Props> = ({item, lastElement}): JSX.Element => {
    const marginBottom = lastElement ? 30 : 14;

    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const deleteItem = () => {
        dispatch(removeCompletelyFromCart(item));
    }

    const renderImage = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{justifyContent: "center"}}>
                <ImageBackground
                    source={{uri: item.image?.url}}
                    style={{width: 92, height: 92}}
                    resizeMode='contain'
                />
            </View>
        );
    };

    const renderInfo = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{
                flex: 1,
                paddingRight: 0,
                justifyContent: 'space-between',
            }}>
                <View style={{
                    marginHorizontal: 10,
                }}>
                    <ProductName item={item} version={1} style={{marginBottom: 3}}/>
                    <ProductPrice item={item} version={1} containerStyle={{marginBottom: 'auto'}}/>
                </View>
                <View style={{justifyContent: "center", marginLeft: 20}}>
                    <AddQuantityButton
                        key={item.id}
                        item={item}
                        containerStyle={{bottom: '0%'}}
                        openExpandedView={true}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    };

    // const renderRightActions = (progress: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation<number>, dragX: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation<number>) => {
    //     const trans = dragX.interpolate({
    //         inputRange: [-100, 0],
    //         outputRange: [0, 100],
    //         extrapolate: 'clamp',
    //     });
    //     return (
    //         <View style={{width: 100, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    //             <Animated.View style={{transform: [{translateX: trans}]}}>
    //                 <View style={{
    //                     backgroundColor: 'red',
    //                     justifyContent: 'center',
    //                     alignItems: 'center',
    //                     width: 100,
    //                     height: '100%',
    //                 }}>
    //                     <Animated.Text
    //                         style={{
    //                             color: 'white',
    //                             fontWeight: '600',
    //                             transform: [{
    //                                 scale: progress.interpolate({
    //                                     inputRange: [0, 1],
    //                                     outputRange: [0.5, 1],
    //                                 }),
    //                             }],
    //                         }}
    //                     >
    //                         Delete
    //                     </Animated.Text>
    //                 </View>
    //             </Animated.View>
    //         </View>
    //     );
    // };

    const swipeableRow = useRef<SwipeableMethods>(null);

    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView>
            <Swipeable
                renderRightActions={(_, progress) =>
                    renderRightActions(_, progress, swipeableRow)
                }
                onSwipeableOpen={deleteItem}
            >
                <View>
                    <View style={{
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        width: '100%',
                        height: 100,
                        marginBottom: marginBottom,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        backgroundColor: 'white',
                    }}>
                        {renderImage()}
                        {renderInfo()}
                    </View>
                    {!lastElement && (
                        <View style={{
                            borderBottomWidth: 0.2,
                            borderColor: 'lightgrey',
                            width: '80%',
                            alignSelf: 'center',
                        }}/>
                    )}
                </View>
            </Swipeable>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
};

export default OrderItem;

Here's my order page where I have a list of orderitems for your curiosity or if it can help in anyway:
import React from 'react';
import {ScrollView, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';

import {text} from '../../text';
import {svg} from '../../assets/svg';
import {useAppDispatch, useAppNavigation, useAppSelector} from '../../hooks';
import {components} from '../../components';
import {tabs, theme} from '../../constants';
import {MAX_ORDER_QUANTITY} from "../../constants/constants";
import {showMessage} from "react-native-flash-message";
import {statusBarHeight} from "../../utils";
import {Feather} from "@expo/vector-icons";
import {setScreen} from "../../store/slices/tabSlice";

const Order = () => {
    const navigation = useAppNavigation();
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const totalPrice = useAppSelector((state) => state.cartSlice.totalPrice) ?? 0;
    const totalWeight = useAppSelector((state) => state.cartSlice.totalQuantityKg);
    const currencyCode = useAppSelector((state) => state.cartSlice.currencyCode) ?? "DZD";
    const cart = useAppSelector((state) => state.cartSlice.list);
    const user = useAppSelector((state) => state.appState.user);

    const isProceedToCheckOutEnabled = totalWeight >= MAX_ORDER_QUANTITY;

    const height = statusBarHeight();

    const renderStatusBar = (): JSX.Element => {
        return (
            <components.StatusBar
                backgroundColor={theme.colors.transparent}
                barStyle='dark-content'
            />
        );
    };

    const renderHeader = (): JSX.Element => {
        return (
            <components.Header
                title='Basket'
            />
        );
    };

    const renderTabBar = (): JSX.Element => {
        return (
            <components.TabBar>
                {tabs.map((item, index) => {
                    return <components.TabBarItem item={item} key={index}/>;
                })}
            </components.TabBar>
        );
    };

    const delivery = 0;

    const renderProductsInCart = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{paddingHorizontal: 12}}>
                {cart.map((item, index, array) => {
                    const lastElement = index === array.length - 1;
                    return (
                        <components.OrderItem
                            key={index}
                            item={item.product}
                            lastElement={lastElement}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </View>
        );
    };

    const navigateToHomeTab = () => {
        dispatch(setScreen('Home'));
        navigation.navigate('TabNavigator');
    };

    const renderCircularButton = () => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={navigateToHomeTab}>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Feather name="plus" size={20} color="black"/>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    };

    const renderEmptyCart = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
                <svg.ShoppingBagSvg/>
                <text.H2 style={{marginTop: 30, marginBottom: 14, fontSize: 18, color: theme.colors.textColor}}>
                    Your basket is empty!
                </text.H2>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', paddingHorizontal: 18, alignItems: "center"}}>
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color: theme.colors.textColor, marginRight: 10, textAlign: "center", paddingBottom: 12, lineHeight: 28}}>Start adding fruits and vegetables by clicking on</Text>
                    {renderCircularButton()}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    };

    const renderTotal = () => {
        return (
            <components.Container
                containerStyle={{
                    marginHorizontal: 20,
                }}
            >
                <components.ContainerItem
                    title='Subtotal'
                    price={`${totalPrice} ${currencyCode}`}
                    titleStyle={{
                        ...theme.fonts.H5,
                        color: theme.colors.textColor,
                        fontSize: 16
                    }}
                    priceStyle={{
                        ...theme.fonts.textStyle_14,
                        color: theme.colors.textColor,
                        fontSize: 16
                    }}
                />
                <components.ContainerItem
                    title='Delivery'
                    price={`${delivery} DZD`}
                    titleStyle={{
                        fontSize: 16
                    }}
                    containerStyle={{
                        marginBottom: 14,
                    }}
                    priceStyle={{
                        fontSize: 16
                    }}
                />
                <components.ContainerLine/>
                <components.ContainerItem
                    title='Total'
                    price={`${totalPrice} ${currencyCode}`}
                    containerStyle={{
                        marginTop: 8,
                        marginBottom: 0,
                    }}
                    titleStyle={{
                        ...theme.fonts.H4,
                        color: theme.colors.textColor,
                        fontSize: 16
                    }}
                    priceStyle={{
                        ...theme.fonts.H4,
                        color: theme.colors.textColor,
                        fontSize: 16
                    }}
                />
            </components.Container>
        );
    };

    const renderContent = (): JSX.Element => {
        return (
            <ScrollView
                contentContainerStyle={{
                    flexGrow: 1,
                    paddingVertical: 20,
                    paddingBottom: 138,
                    paddingHorizontal: cart.length === 0 ? 20 : 0,
                    justifyContent: cart.length === 0 ? 'center' : 'flex-start',
                }}
            >
                {cart.length === 0 ? renderEmptyCart() : renderProductsInCart()}
                {cart.length !== 0 && renderTotal()}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    };

    const onPressProceedToCheckoutButton = () => {
        if (!user) {
            navigation.navigate('SignIn');
        } else if (cart.length !== 0) {
            navigation.navigate('Checkout');
        }
    }

    const renderProceedToCheckoutButton = () => {
        if (cart.length <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        return (
            <View style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                padding: 20,
                bottom: 58,
            }}>
                <components.Button
                    title={'Proceed to checkout'}
                    onPress={() => onPressProceedToCheckoutButton()}
                    disabled={!isProceedToCheckOutEnabled}
                    onPressDisabled={() => {
                        showMessage({
                            message: 'Oops!',
                            description: `Your basket needs to be ${MAX_ORDER_QUANTITY} kg to checkout`,
                            type: 'danger',
                            icon: 'danger',
                            position: 'top',
                            duration: 2000,
                            hideOnPress: true,
                            style: {
                                zIndex: 9999,
                                marginTop: height,
                            }
                        });
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    };

    return (
        <components.SmartView>
            {renderStatusBar()}
            {renderHeader()}
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                {renderContent()}
                {renderProceedToCheckoutButton()}
            </View>
            {renderTabBar()}
        </components.SmartView>
    );
};

const styles = {
    container: {
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 20,
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 1},
        shadowOpacity: 0.22,
        shadowRadius: 2.22,
        elevation: 4,
    },
    button: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
};

export default Order;

